# Error while trying to connect openfire using smack on android

Tags: android, chat, openfire, smack

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder =  XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("test", "test");
    configBuilder.setResource("test");
    configBuilder.setServiceName("37.139.26.142");
    configBuilder.setHost("37.139.26.142");
    configBuilder.setPort(5222);
    configBuilder.setSendPresence(true);
    configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    configBuilder.setSecurityMode(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required );
    SASLMechanism mechanism = new SASLDigestMD5Mechanism();
    SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism(mechanism);
    SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("SCRAM-SHA-1");
    SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");
    AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
    try {
        connection.connect();
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        connection.login();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm currently trying to handshake my android application and my openfire server(working on ubuntu). But I couldnt. I dont get any fail or something. Just nothing happens. And that feels bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I find out this is not about Android part, this is about Openfire part. Because I couldnt connect it with Spark and I saw this in Logcat;

```
W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '37.139.26.142:5222' failed because java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /37.139.26.142 (port 5222) after 30000ms
```

Then I did some research and tried somethings and I saw it is about Ubuntu(at least for me). Then I moved my openfire server to Centos. Then I could be able to connect with Spark to it. Then I got another problem.

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

And I solved this problem with this code below. I hope this can help others.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true;
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("test", "test");
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        configBuilder.setResource("test");
        configBuilder.setServiceName("enter your server ip here");
        configBuilder.setHost("eneter your server ip here");
        configBuilder.setPort(5222);
        configBuilder.setSendPresence(true);
        configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("SCRAM-SHA-1");
        SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");
        SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");

        XMPPTCPConnection connection;
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
        // Connect to the server
        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Log into the server

        try {
            connection.login();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you try to send a message? Are you sure that you are not connected?
Did you check on Openfire admin that your test user is not connected?

First I suggest you to try to send a message:

```
ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("anotheruser@yourdomain", new MessageListener() {
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
    }
});

try {
    newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
}
catch (XMPPException e) {
    System.out.println("Error Delivering block");
}
```

I got this code from : http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/messaging.html

Another suggestion is to disable the SecurityMode, just for a test.

```
configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
```

If nothing of this works, try to use the configuration below, which works for me.

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();

config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
config.setServiceName(serverAddress);
config.setHost(serverAddress);
config.setPort(5222);
config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());

try {
    connection.connect();
} catch (SmackException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    connection.login(loginUser, passwordUser);
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SmackException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I've tried your sayings and some other thing since night. And now I believe it is not about android part. It is about Openfire part. I am seeing this at Android Logcat;

`W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '37.139.26.142:5222' failed because java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /37.139.26.142 (port 5222) after 30000ms`

And I checked my server [here](https://xmpp.net/)but it failed.

(I am giving these IP adresses because this doesn't have anything. This is just test server built by me for training on this.)

Comment: I changed my hosts operating system from Ubuntu to Centos. Now I can reach from Spark client. But still cant access via Android. I'm getting

`org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.` error now.

Comment: do you open your 5222 port for any ip?
Are you using this config like this ?
             config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);

Comment: I solved it. Yes I used it like you said. You can check first post for code. Thank you for help.

Comment: You are welcome.
I run my server on Ubuntu 14 in AWS and it`s working normally